# Simplify these products of permutations

Tags: permutations

Can someone please explain how to get these answers? Everytime I think I understand the method, I end up getting a completely different answer to the one provided. How exactly do you go about simplifying these?
[Note: Read from left to right]
$$(i)\;\;\; (1,2,3).(2,4)(1,3,5) = (1,4,2,5)$$
$$(ii)\;\;\; (1,3,4)(2,5).(2,3,4)(1,5) = (1,4,5,3,2) $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take for example the first one  (from left to right)

1 goes to 2, then 2 goes to 4 and that's all, so $\,1\to 4\,$

2 goes to 3, 3 goes to 5 so $\,2\to 5\,$

3 goes to 1, 1 goes to 3. so 3 is a fixed point

4 goes to 2, so $\,4\to 2\,$

5 goes to 1 so $\,5\to 1\,$ and we cflose the cycle: $\,(1\;4\;2\;5)$

Final aclaration: it seems to me that the big majority of authors prefer to do the cycles product *from right to left*. Watch this when trying to read other books and, anyway, always read the author's definition of product of cycles.

Comment: Who cares? we follow a single cycle: $$1\to 2\to 4\Longrightarrow 1\to 4\,\,\text{in this cycle's product}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio that's a very clear and helpful method, thank you!

Comment: Anytime, @Mathlete ....

Answer (score 2):

$$(i)\;\;\; (1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5) =(1,2,3)(4)(5)\cdot(1,3,5)(2,4)=(1,4,2,5)(3)=(1,4,2,5)$$
$$(1\to2)(2\to 4)=(1\to4)$$
$$(2\to3)(3\to5)=(2\to5)$$
$$(3\to1)(1\to3)=(3\to3)$$
$$(4\to4)(4\to2)=(4\to2)$$
$$(3\to5)(5\to1)=(3\to1)$$
$$1\to4\to2\to5,3\to3$$
$$(ii)\;\;\; (1,3,4)(2,5)\cdot(2,3,4)(1,5) = (1,4,5,3,2) $$
$$(1\to3\to4)\Rightarrow(1\to4)$$
$$(2\to5\to1)\Rightarrow(2\to1)$$
$$(3\to4\to2)\Rightarrow(3\to2)$$
$$(4\to1\to5)\Rightarrow(4\to5)$$
$$(5\to2\to3)\Rightarrow(5\to3)$$
$$1\to4\to5\to3\to2$$

Answer (score 1):

To find, for example, $(1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5)$ you need to apply it on every $1\leq i\leq 5$:
$$\begin{array}{l}
[1](1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5)=[2](2,4)(1,3,5)=4\\
[2](1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5)=[3](2,4)(1,3,5)=5\\
[3](1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5)=[1](2,4)(1,3,5)=3\\
[4](1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5)=[4](2,4)(1,3,5)=2\\
[5](1,2,3)\cdot(2,4)(1,3,5)=[5](2,4)(1,3,5)=1
\end{array}$$
Hence, by writing it as a permutation, starting with one, you have: $(1,4,2,5)$